# What does the bracket notation $[G : H]$, with $H$ being a subgroup of $G$ mean in group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am asked to compute $[G : H]$, with $H$ being a subgroup of $G$. What does this bracket notation mean in group theory?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup

Comment: Please don't ask a definition here, before you have tried to look it up yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a cardinality of coset space $G/H=\{xH|x\in G\}$. So it can be rewritten...
$$|G/H|=[G:H]$$

Comment: I think it is better to say in a comment, that one can search a definition.